# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in simplebar-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, simplebar

I am getting Error while using simple react package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplebar-react

> simplebar-react.esm.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at simplebar-react.esm.js:27 at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803) at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:16816) at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18645) at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188) at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237) at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292) at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203) at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154) at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=simplebar-react+Object+is+not+a+function+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.